# How can I avoid GetAwaiter().GetResult in an overridden page

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

I'm using VS2022 and Net7 web App.

I have this page, to handle common stuff so I don't have to put it in every page

```
public class ApplicationPageModel : PageModel
{        
    public IActionResult? OnGet()
    {
        //cookie handling
        //page set up
        //security checking
        //etc

        return null;
    }
}
```

Then all my other pages look like this

```
public class PermissionsModel : ApplicationPageModel
{
    public override async void OnPageHandlerExecuted(PageHandlerExecutedContext context)
    {
        if (context.HandlerMethod!.MethodInfo.Name == nameof(OnGet))
        {
            string page = HttpContext.Request.Query["id"].ToString();

            //page specific code goes here'
            //do something awaitable here
        }

        base.OnPageHandlerExecuted(context);

    }
}
```

I can't use `OnGet` in the actual page because I get this error

`An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request. InvalidOperationException: Multiple handlers matched. The following handlers matched route data and had all constraints satisfied:`

The problem is using `OnPageHandlerExecuted` I then have to use .GetAwaiter().GetResult() on my async method because the Razor page renders before my awaitable API call completes. So any model updates (null) aren't complete so I get null exceptions in the page. For exmaple if I use:-

`@foreach(var stuff in Model.Stuff)` //Model.Stuff is always null because that method completes after the page.

Without the override using a normal `OnGet` everything is fine, but then I have to put code in every page and I'm planning alot of pages in my app.

I have no issues with using `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` but I'm being told its either not safe or not a good idea. How else could I acheive the same in a safe way.

Any ideas anyone?

Comment: Have you tried making OnGet async? and then normally awaiting

Comment: "I then have to use .GetAwaiter().GetResult() on my async method because the Razor page renders before my awaitable API call completes" Eeeeehm, that's why we have the `await` actually. However it shouldn't make a difference except the potential deadlocks on `GetResult()` of course.

Comment: Seems like your `OnGet` should actually be some `BeforeGet` or similar, as this function is not a request-handler but just a "normal" utility-method . Having said this, you should favour composition over inheritance, which is not *deriving* `ApplicationPageModel`, but just *using* it (which also avoids deriving this class from `PageModel` in the first place which furthermor avoids naming-collisions with a `Get`-router-function).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd argue your actual problem isn't about `await` or `GetAwaiter`, but about a pretty unfortunate class-design. Your base-class seems to be in no way related to a `PageModel`, but happens to have this inheritance only to share some common functionality on all your pages. This is best done using [*composition instead of inheritance*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance). So after all your `ApplicationModel`-class is just a utility-class. This is also indicated by your `OnGet`-method just returning `null` instead of a valid response. So instead of *deriving* that utility-class, just *use* it:

```
class static ApplicationHelpers
{
    public static async Task DoSomething() { await something }
}
public class MyPage : PageModel
{
    // now you can easily implement OnGet here, no more naming-collisions
    public Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync()
    {
        // do the commmon stuff
        await ApplicationHelpers.DoSomething();

        // do the page-specific stuff here
    }
}
```

As `ApplicationHelpers.DoSomething` (or whatever you name it) now makes some request as well, you are free to make it `async` and thus to avoid this annoying `GetAwaiter`-thing in the first place. Of course you should consider to inject the dependency to this helper-class in your `Program.cs`-file somehow, for brevity I omited that and made the class `static`.

If you can't change the inheritance for whatever reason, you could at least just rename the `OnGet`-function in your base-class, as the method is not really a request-handler. Instead it is just some common logic that should happen when a request is done. So just call that function withkin every request-handler like so:

```
class ApplicationPageModel : PageModel
{
    public async Task DoSomething() { await something }
}
public class MyPage : PageModel
{
    // now you can easily implement OnGet here, no more naming-collisions
    public Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync()
    {
        // do the commmon stuff
        await base.DoSomething();

        // do the page-specific stuff here
    }
}
```

Comment: I might give that a go. I'm trying to do the least amount of code possible as I have a load of pages that will use whatever method I end up with. Oh, and OnBeforeGet didn't work, returns a null again without using `.GetAwaiter...` I'll post/accept an answer in a few days, thanks all

Comment: @djack109 your `ApplicationModel.OnGet`-function *literally* returns `null` (unless this is some dummy-code and not your actual).

Comment: Yes, dummy code. In reality, it returns a redirect or nothing depending on all the checking its doing. Because if is doesn't redirect I want the actual page to handle whatever happens next

Comment: @djack109 I still see no valid reason for inheritance here. You can redirect from one page to another one without any inheritance-relation of course. Hard to know without any clue about what common and special things means.

Comment: Thanks, its ok your answers have given me food for thought. :)

Comment: I'm still working on this (as time allows). In my Inherited model `ApplicationPageModel` I need to access `ViewData`, `IConfiguration`, `Request` and `Response` objects. I think that's why I went with the inherited option rather than a helper as it was less code to worry about. The only thing I have to do is inherit the class and I get the other stuff (sic) for free, but obviously cause myself other problems lol.

Comment: @djack109 then you may try to make `ApplicationPageMode.OnGet` a `virtual` method and `override` it in your derived class.

Comment: I kinda went halfway. `OnGet` as `virtual` didn't help as I still need the base class `OnGet` to fire as well. So I just renamed the base to `OnGetStatuUp` then in my pages I call `base.OnGetStartUp()` (I can ditch `base.`). This gets me to what I need, so for all the pointers, I will mark this as Answered :)